# Java Operator Precedence example

Tags: java, operator-precedence

I know the [Operator Precedence list](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/), but I just cannot figure out what is the execution precedence in this code in "LINE 1". What Object is created before? For example: the `My String` or the `new Precedence()`? How can we apply the Operator Precedence rule in this example?

```
public class Precedence {
    public String s;
    public static void main (String ... args){
        String a = new Precedence().s="My String"; // LINE 1
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**
`My String`

Comment: Note that operator precedence is different than execution order.

Comment: how can I know this is a case of execution order?

Comment: @ThurfirHawat I don't know what 'how can I know this is a case of execution order' means, but the only operator-precedence issue here is between `=` and `.`. There are several *other* issues here, namely associativity of the `=` operator, and the fact that the `String` valued `"My String"` is created by the compiler and class-loader, not by this code.

Comment: i would say the dot(.) operator is first followed by assaignment operator(=) will try to back it up by proof

Comment: @EJP doesn't have "only one operator here". We have 2 operators of the same type, and that is exactly the issue here, which one executes before? Depending on which one executes before, we have the creation of the String first, or the new Precedence()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
String a = new Precedence().s="My String"; // LINE 1
```

is a [local variable declaration statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.4) with an initialization expression.

> Every time it is executed, the declarators are processed in order from
>   left to right. If a declarator has an initializer, the initializer is
>   evaluated and its value is assigned to the variable.

`a` is the declarator. It's evaluated to produce a variable (itself). Then the initialization expression is evaluated.

This

```
new Precedence().s = "My String";
```

is [an assignment expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26). The left hand side of the operator is evaluated first to produce a variable, so `new Precedence()` is evaluated first, instantiates the class `Precedence`, producing a reference to an object. Then the right hand side of the assignment is evaluated, the `String` literal `"My String"`, so a reference to a `String` object is produced. Then the assignment happens assigning the reference to the `String` object to the variable `s` of the object referenced by the value returned by the new instance creation expression.

Finally, since

> At run time, the result of the assignment expression is the value of
>   the variable after the assignment has occurred.

The value that was assigned to the field `s` of the `Precedence` object is also assigned to the variable `a`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the bytecode:

```
public static transient varargs main([Ljava/lang/String;)V
   L0
    LINENUMBER 8 L0
    NEW Precedence
    DUP
    INVOKESPECIAL Precedence.<init> ()V
    LDC "My String"
    DUP_X1
    PUTFIELD Precedence.s : Ljava/lang/String;
    ASTORE 1
```

This shows the following execution order:

1. Create `Precedence` object.
2. Assign `My String` constant to `Precedence.s`.
3. Assign it also to `a`.

Comment: There is no step here that initializes a string constant. It should be 2. Assign `My String` constant to `Precedence.s`, and then 3. Assign it also to `a`.

Comment: where are the assign of the `s` field to local variable `a` defined. Did you know why doesn't show in the javap -c ?

Comment: It's done by `ASTORE 1`.  Don't understand the second half of your question.

Comment: I mean, why the javap -p don't explicit show the `a` local variable reference like the javap did for the `s` variable PUTFIELD Precedence.s : Ljava/lang/String; . There is a reason or something?

Comment: I found why: http://cs.au.dk/~mis/dOvs/jvmspec/ref--3.html  . it references by the number of declaration. tnx.

Comment: @ThufirHawat If you compile your program with the `-g` option (for `javac`), you can then use the the `-l` option in `javap` to list the local variable tables.

Answer (score 1):

There is tool javap, dissasembler, which will show you bytecode and from there you can conclude what is order of execution. It will output comments.

```
$ /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/javap -c Precedence.class 
Compiled from "Precedence.java"
public class Precedence {
  public java.lang.String s;

  public Precedence();
    Code:
       0: aload_0       
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return        

  public static void main(java.lang.String...);
    Code:
       0: new           #2                  // class Precedence
       3: dup           
       4: invokespecial #3                  // Method "<init>":()V
       7: ldc           #4                  // String My String
       9: dup_x1        
      10: putfield      #5                  // Field s:Ljava/lang/String;
      13: astore_1      
      14: getstatic     #6                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      17: aload_1       
      18: invokevirtual #7                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      21: return        
}
```

javap is part of JDK, path is on Linux, switch -c is Disassemble the code. Here is definition of instruction ldc, it is not obvious what it does

```
push a constant #index from a constant pool (String, int or float) onto the stack
```

Comment: where are the assign of the `s` field to local variable `a` defined. Did you know why doesn't show in the javap -c ?

Comment: @ThufirHawat `astore_1` stores string to variable a, prior to that `ldc` puts string on the stack, `dup_x1` duplicates it, `putfield` loads first copy into objectref and finally the second copy goes to a. You can see that `aload_1` loads it for printing.